# Grouping Pandas DataFrame Rows According to an Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame and I'm trying to group the rows according to a column value, and merge some rows into lists. Allow me to elaborate:

The DataFrame that I have looks like this:

```
industry     index     entities
cars         0         ['Norway', 'it']
cars         0         ['Mercedes', 'they']
cars         0         ['it', 'EV', 'its']
nature       1         ['fox', 'it']
nature       1         ['them', 'rabbits']
nature       2         ['whale', 'it']
```

The desired DataFrame should look like this:

```
industry     index     entities
cars         0         [ ['Norway', 'it'], ['Mercedes', 'they'], ['it', 'EV', 'its'] ]
nature       1         [ ['fox', 'it'], ['them', 'rabbits'] ]
nature       2         ['whale', 'it']
```

I'm basically trying to group the rows according to the industry and index, while merging the values of column `entities` into lists.

I've made attempts such as

```
df.groupby('industry')['index'].apply(list)
```

but they are giving me completely different results.

How might I be able to accomplish what I want? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need change `index` to `entities` after `groupby` for processing column `entities` and also grouping by `list` - ['industry', 'index'] in `groupby` statement:

```
df = df.groupby(['industry', 'index'])['entities'].apply(list).reset_index()
print (df)
  industry  index                                         entities
0     cars      0  [[Norway, it], [Mercedes, they], [it, EV, its]]
1   nature      1                     [[fox, it], [them, rabbits]]
2   nature      2                                    [[whale, it]]
```

If need last value not in nested list because only one value per group is it possible by `if-else` with lambda function:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['industry', 'index'])['entities']
         .apply(lambda x: x.tolist() if len(x) != 1 else x.iat[0])
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
  industry  index                                         entities
0     cars      0  [[Norway, it], [Mercedes, they], [it, EV, its]]
1   nature      1                     [[fox, it], [them, rabbits]]
2   nature      2                                      [whale, it]
```

EDIT:

If in column `entities` are only string represenation of lists you can convert values to lists by `ast` module before solution above:

```
print (type(df['entities'].iat[0]))
<class 'str'>

import ast
df['entities'] = df['entities'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

print (type(df['entities'].iat[0]))
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer it works great! I have a follow-up question, though. When I perform the grouping as you suggested, it does indeed group the lists to be a single list of lists according to each index. However, I noticed that when that happens the lists that are elements get converted to strings. Is there any way that I can prevent that from happening? Please let me know if it would be more appropriate to ask a new question.

Comment: @Seankala - Are lists in column `enties` ? If not, try `import ast` and `df['entities'] = df['entities'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` before my solution.

Comment: Thanks! Just did as you suggested and works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the elements in `entities` are `list`:

```
df.groupby(['industry', 'index'])['entities'].apply(lambda x: [l for l in x]).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  industry  index                                         entities
0     cars      0  [[Norway, it], [Mercedes, they], [it, EV, its]]
1   nature      1                     [[fox, it], [them, rabbits]]
2   nature      2                                    [[whale, it]]
```